# Does embryonic development mimic (partly at least) the evolution of organisms on earth?

Tags: evolution, embryology

What do we know about the forces/mechanisms which lead to this seemingly "fast forward" evolution stages of the embryo? What are the theories dealing with this idea?

Comment: You might want to read up upon the recapitulation theory, and reword your question, to be more specific.

Comment: Can you provide some kind of evidence for your claim? In the meantime, I'm voting to close.

Comment: @canadianer he is talking about the recapitulation theory by Haeckel. Ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny The developmental history of the organism recapitulates the developmental history of the species.

Comment: I vote too close because the question asks to review a theory, which is too broad to my opinion.

Comment: seems like OP received an answer from @RoverEye already

Comment: @RoverEye Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Voted to reopen, but still feel that the OP should give more background, e.g. by pointing to cases where recapitulation/fast-forward seems to be a good explanation. Why do you think that "*embryonic development [should] mimic [...] the evolution of organisms*"? What made you ask this particular question?

Comment: @RoverEye Yes I saw your first comment. I'm not familiar with the theory but Wikipedia describes it as a "largely discredited hypothesis". If that's true, it is not evidence for the claim that embryonic development mimics evolution.

Comment: @canadianer Indeed it has. This paper gives the latest (I think) view on whats going on. Irie, Naoki, and Shigeru Kuratani. "Comparative transcriptome analysis reveals vertebrate phylotypic period during organogenesis." Nature communications 2 (2011): 248.

Comment: @fileunderwater Essentially the hinted wikipedia article says it all: the vague impression is/was there and I was happy to learn how this idea developed and influenced other areas and got debunked... or not.

Comment: @pointernil I'm familiar with the theory, and my comment was meant to make the question more complete and self-contained. At the moment, the question is probably very unclear for readers that are unaware of the ontogeny-recapitulates-phylogeny theory.

Comment: You only need to read Stephen Jay Gould's entire book on this topic, I believe it is called "Ontogeny and Phylogeny." He argues persuasively that there is no support for Haeckel's ancient theory.